# Find a html tag using BeautifulSoup in Python

Tags: python, html, django, beautifulsoup

I want to find a specific tag in a html code like if there are 2  tags then how can i get the contents of the second tag and not the first one which soup.find(id='contact1') does here is the example html code

```
<table align="center"><th id="contact">STUDENT ID</th><th id="contact">NAME</th><th id="contact">   Phone </th><th id="contact"> NO.</th>
<p align="center" style="display:compact; font-size:18px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#CC3300">
</p><tr>
<td id="contact1">
2011XXA4438F </td> <td id="contact1"> SAM SRINIVAS KRISHNAGOPAL</td> <td id="contact1"> 9894398690 </td> <td id="contact1"> </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

What i want to do is to extract '2011XXA4438F' as a string how can i do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<td id="contact1">` is the *first* tag with an id of `"contact1"`. To obtain it, then `soup.find` is all you need:

```
>>> print soup.find(id='contact1').text.strip()
2011XXA4438F
```

If you're looking for other tags, then you'll want to use `find_all`:

```
>>> print soup.find_all(id='contact1')
[<td id="contact1">
2011XXA4438F </td>, <td id="contact1"> SAM SRINIVAS KRISHNAGOPAL</td>, <td id="contact1"> 9894398690 </td>, <td id="contact1"> </td>]
```

Comment: when i am using the above code soup.find(id='contact1').text.strip() it returns me SAM SRINIVAS KRISHNAGOPAL i cant figure out why is it happening..

Comment: and according to your answer is there a way to get 'SAM SRINIVAS KRISHNAGOPAL'..?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure .find only gives you the first element that matches your query. Try using .findAll instead.

Check documentation here - http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html

EDIT: Misread your post. Just to understand completely. Do you want to always find the 2nd occurance of "id='contact1'"?

There is probably something more elegant, but you could do something like

```
v = soup.find_all(id='contact1')
length = 0
for x in v:
    length += 1
    if length = 2: #set number according to which occurrence you want. 
        #here is the second occurrence of id='contact1'.
```

The above is completely non tested and just written directly here. And i've only just started using python, some there is probably a more efficient way of doing it :-)

Comment: yes i want a way to find 'n'th occurrence of id=contact1 is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it this way:
target = soup.find("table", {"id": "contact1"})

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.